# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'

Tags: python, discord.py, google-sheets-api

I was able to somewhat merge my own code for a Discord bot with the someone that has written a code to write data onto Google Sheets via user inputs. However when I tried introducing an economy system to it, I keep getting errors. What should happen is that when someone enters this command:

`!bet result[0],result[1],result[2]`

I would take the value of result[2] and deduct it to their currency, in my case, tokens. I wrote it as such:

```
@client.command()
async def bet(ctx,message):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    users = await token_data()
    user = ctx.author

    if message.content.startswith('!b '):

        msg = message.content[3:]
        result = [x.strip() for x in msg.split(',')]
        SPREADSHEET_ID = 'Sheet ID here'
        RANGE_NAME = result[0]+'!A2'
        FIELDS = 3
        token_bet = int(result[2])
          
    if len(result) == FIELDS:
            print(message.created_at)
            DATA = [ctx.author.name] + [str(ctx.author.id)] + [str(message.created_at)] + result
            sheet.add(SPREADSHEET_ID, RANGE_NAME, DATA)
            await message.channel.send('Thank you! Your bet has been placed :)')
           
    else:
            await message.channel.send('Error: Please try again!'.format(FIELDS,FIELDS-1))

            users[str(user.id)]["token"] -= token_bet
```

The problem is whenever I try to do the command, it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Any ideas as to why? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: your `message` object is a string, but your code expects it to be a different object type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you copied your code from somewhere where `on_message` was used, and put it in a command.  In `on_message`, `message` is a [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) object, so to get the content you have to use `message.content` however in a command, you will just get the raw string.  I suggest modifying your command def to:

```
async def bet(ctx, *, message):
```

This will ensure that the entire message content gets passed to your command.  Then replace all instances of `message.content` in your command with just `message`

EDIT:
Also, if you have something like `message.channel.send` you will need to change this to `ctx.send`, to send a message to the context

I would suggest looking at the [Commands documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) if you have any further questions

Comment: Thank you! It looks like I'm on the right path, but now I have a different problem. it's now giving me this error:

`token_bet = (result[2])
IndexError: list index out of range`

I still have `msg = message[3:]` and the x.strip part, so I'm pretty sure result[2] should be inside the range. Or maybe I misread something? I just wanted to get the first and the last entry in three entries.

Comment: `message[3:]` will get the first 4 characters in your message.  result is a list that is created by splitting your `msg` on every `,`.  You are getting an out of range because you are trying to access item index 2 of this list, and there are less than 3 items in your list.

Comment: Sorry `message[3:]` will remove the first 3 characters, this was likley to remove the prefix when this code was in `on_message`

Comment: What would you suggest doing? The main point of the part of the code is to get the first and last entries on a message that has three values on it.

Comment: you do not need `message.content[3:]`.  Just do some basic debugging of the code and make sure your variables are getting set to the correct values you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no class defined for `message`.
If your variable is some sore of string input, which i assume, you need to declare this string as an instance of a (already given or self-written) class object, which inherits the attribute `content`.

Given this piece of code theres is no way to give you further advice, unfortunately!